# Make laptop fans always run at maximum speed

Tags: overheating, fan, fancontrol

I have a **Dell Precision M90 laptop**, which has two fans. I just want both the fans to run at maximum speed all the time. I have installed and tried `i8kmon.conf` file.

Comment: What did you try with `i8kmon.conf` and what happened when you did?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. This video really helped me:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNVPkkmnsWI

Now I'm able to make both fans run at maximum speed (12000RPM).

Comment: These are the steps:

Comment: This method works for any DELL laptop
1. Install lm-sensors from either terminal or software-center.
2. Open terminal and type: sudo sensors-detect
3. Type yes to all
4. Open /etc/modules file
5. Type sensors in terminal
6. Install i8kutils from either terminal or software-center
7. Create the configuration file i8kmon.conf in /etc/
8. Paste the code in there. Or you can just copy the i8kmon.conf file there.
9. Restart.